# Write a file with bash, executed by PHP

Tags: php, bash

I have this code in PHP:

```
<?php

echo "<pre>doing..\n</pre>";

$output = shell_exec('./new.sh arg1 arg2');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

echo "<pre>done</pre>";

?>
```

That execute a bash file that receive some arguments.
The bash file is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World!" >> $1.txt
echo "File created!"
```

It should appends a new line on the file called "arg1.txt" because of `$1` is `argument_1`.

When I execute the shell normally it works perfectly, but when I try to execute with PHP i get this HTML output:

```
doing..

File created!

done
```

That should be correct, but no file has been created... why?

**UPDATE_1**

If I execute the `index.php` file in the command line, it works perfectly, therefore PHP does not have permission problems. Probably it is a problem of Apache2. But I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: Did you look in the right place? `$output = shell_exec('pwd; ./new.sh arg1 arg2');` should also show you _where_ it was created. Otherwise it could be a permission issue. Hard to tell with so little information.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf it says /var/www/html as expected, but no file created.

Comment: Does the process that runs `php` have the rights to write files there?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf how do I check it?

Comment: @Northumber: Works fine on `PHP 5.5.36`, most likely permission issue, post `ls -lrth /var/www/html` for the current

Comment: I have PHP 7.0 for some compatibility reason. But I don't think is a problem of version. @Inian

Comment: @Inian it says my user, but first where root. But also with root no file has been created

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

By giving permissions to apache2 to write on the `www` folder:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```